# AdView doesn't show in a LinearLayout

Tags: java, android, android-layout, nullpointerexception

Here is my XML code

```
 <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
tools:context="com.techdrive.hindimovietrailers.DetailsActivity"
tools:showIn="@layout/activity_details">


<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">


<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">


        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:cardview="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/card1"
            cardview:cardCornerRadius="5dp"
            cardview:cardBackgroundColor="@android:color/white"
            cardview:cardElevation="4dp"
            android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
            cardview:cardUseCompatPadding="true"
            android:layout_height="230dp"
            android:layout_margin="@dimen/margine_card">


            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="200dp">


                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="170dp"
                    android:layout_height="180dp"
                    android:id="@+id/image_url"

                    android:background="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
                    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" />


                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                    android:text="Title"
                    android:maxLines="2"
                    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/image_url"
                    android:id="@+id/title_movie"
                    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"

                    />


                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                    android:text="Released Date:"
                    android:paddingBottom="10dp"
                    android:id="@+id/released_date"
                    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/image_url"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/title_movie"
                    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/title_movie"
                    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/title_movie" />



                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                    android:text="Date"
                    android:maxLines="2"
                    android:id="@+id/date_movie"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/released_date"
                    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/image_url"
                    />



                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                    android:text="Genery:"
                    android:id="@+id/genery"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/date_movie"
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/image_url"
                    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />



                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                    android:text="Genery Description"
                    android:id="@+id/genery_movie"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/genery"
                    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/image_url"
                    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/image_url" />



                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                    android:text="Rating:"
                    android:id="@+id/rating"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/genery_movie"
                    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/image_url"
                    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/image_url" />



                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                    android:text="rating"
                    android:id="@+id/rating_movie"
                    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/rating"
                    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/rating"
                    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/rating" />

            </RelativeLayout>
        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>



        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:cardview="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_below="@+id/card1"
            android:id="@+id/card2"
            cardview:cardCornerRadius="5dp"
            cardview:cardBackgroundColor="@android:color/white"
            cardview:cardElevation="4dp"
            android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
            cardview:cardUseCompatPadding="true"
            android:layout_height="180dp"
            android:layout_margin="@dimen/margine_card">



            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="180dp">



                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                    android:text="Details:"
                    android:id="@+id/details_movie"
                    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"

                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />



                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                    android:text="Run Time:"
                    android:id="@+id/runtime"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/details_movie"
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />



                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                    android:text="run"
                    android:id="@+id/run_movie"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/details_movie"
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />



                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                    android:text="Region:"
                    android:id="@+id/textView"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/runtime"/>
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                    android:text="region"
                    android:id="@+id/region_movie"
                    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/textView"
                    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/run_movie"
                    android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/run_movie" />



                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                    android:text="Bufget:"
                    android:id="@+id/budget"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/textView"
                    />


                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                    android:text="budget"
                    android:id="@+id/budget_movie"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/region_movie"
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />



                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                    android:text="Revenue:"
                    android:id="@+id/revenue"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/budget"
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />


                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                    android:text="revenue"
                    android:id="@+id/revenue_movie"
                    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/revenue"
                    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/run_movie"
                    android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/run_movie" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                    android:text="Country:"
                    android:id="@+id/country"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/revenue"

                    />


                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                    android:text="country"
                    android:id="@+id/country_movie"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/revenue_movie"
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />


            </RelativeLayout>
        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

        <include layout="@layout/sum_content" />

    </LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
        xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/adView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        ads:adSize="SMART_BANNER"
        ads:adUnitId="ca-app-pub-9538253184459093/3329616766" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

When I run my application my ad not showing. I am using `LinearLayout` and `RelativeLayout` to organize my Layout.
So where i put my adview xml to show it.
I want to show ad in below of the screen.So that user can easily scroll all over the element of the screen and ad would perfectly show.

Comment: Try not to use nested `RelativeLayout` with `LinearLayout` since it can heavily affect your ui performance.

Comment: @lulian thnx but i can't show my ad.

Comment: I understand that and I'm looking right now for the problem, but I wanted to tell some optimisations that will improve a lot your ui. Also, I see that you have a lot of unnecessary parent layouts. Consider reading [this](http://developer.android.com/intl/zh-cn/training/improving-layouts/optimizing-layout.html) for a better understanding.

Comment: And please post the content of `sum_content.xml`

Comment: @lulian thnx bro i don't need it anymore.